# Graphviz - how to set different layouts for each subgraph?

Tags: graphviz

Graph is built by Graphviz:

```
graph {
    layout=circo;
    subgraph cluster_0 {
        1 -- { 2 3 4 5 6 }
        2 -- { 3 4 5 6 }
        3 -- { 4 5 6 }
        4 -- { 5 6 }
        5 -- { 6 }
    };

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        a -- b;
        a -- c;
        a -- d;
        1 -- a;
    };
}
```

This command is executed to save output as PNG file

```
dot -Tpng example.dot -o example.png
```

The result:

[image]

I would like to set different layouts for each subgraphs. For example, **circo** for cluster_0 and **twopi** for cluster_1. How can I do it?

Comment: This is AFAIK not possible with graphviz.

Comment: There is no straight-forward way.  You could layout each separately with -Tdot option to produce "dot" output files, then use GVPR (or any language) to adjust the "pos" values.  Not trivial but doable.  Moving nodes is pretty easy, edges are more of a pain.  Don't forget to adjust the bb values.

Comment: gvpack (https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf) might also do what you want